# How to check if object has property and property value is true in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to check if the following object has the property `forums` and if that property value is `true`.

```
{forums: true, pages: true, photos: true, videos: true}
```

I am using TypeScript Angular 5.

I do this for now and works fine.

```
let item = 'forums';
if ( this.itemsmodel.hasOwnProperty(item) ) {
   //Which is true. 
   if (this.itemsmodel[item]) {
          item = item;
   } else {
          item = 'pages';
   }
}
```

Is there an Angular way or TypeScript way for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Shortest way ,this will check both by default :**

```
if(this.itemsmodel[item])
```

First it will try to fetch `this.itemsmodel` of `item` if there is not then it will return `undefined` and if it's found then it will return value,

---

**Same but long way of doing :**

```
if(this.itemsmodel[item] && this.itemsmodel[item] === true)
```

Here first will check if key exists , second will check for the value

---

**As result you can convert your code to something like this :**

```
let item = 'forums';
if (this.itemsmodel[item]) {
        item = item;
} else {
        item = 'pages';
}
```

Comment: What if `itemsmodel` is boolean?

Comment: `if('name_of_field' in this.itemsmodel)` , @Pontios